# Same resource with different rights in REST API

Tags: api, rest

I have a project management application where users can create services (time services, expenses, material) on projects. In the app, user rights for project management can be defined:

- no access
- read only on all projects
- read/write on all projects

For creating services projects are visible to users independent on project rights, but instead dependent on project membership.

What is the best way to implement these use cases in a REST-API?
How to distinguish whether projects should be returned

- depending on the user rights
- depending on project membership

Remark: The user is authenticated as app user and his permissions for the app are known

1. One resource *projects*, one GET endpoint and distinguish by a parameter
2. One resource *projects*, two GET endpoints with different parameters
3. Two resources *projects* and *projectsforservicerecording*
4. Two resources *projects* and *projects/forservicerecording*
5. Two resources *projects* and *me/projectsforservicerecording*
6. ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to implement these use cases in a REST-API?

How would you design a website to support these concerns?

On the web, you would start by identifying the documents that you need.  Each document would need a unique identifier (which can be used to link documents to each other), and you would determine which requests for a document are authorized by comparing the information in the authorization header to your internal policies.

If Bob's copy of a document is supposed to differ from Alice's copy of a document, then what you have are two *different* documents, with different identifiers.

Spelling conventions for document identifiers is entirely up to you, so long as the URI are consistent with the production rules defined by RFC 3986.  So you can encode document identifying information into the path segments, or into the query part.  Both are fine (there are trade offs, of course -- a query with key value pairs is convenient on the web, because HTML forms can be use to supply values, and browsers know the production rules to convert values provided in input controls into a target URI).

Comment: `How would you design a website to support these concerns?` - I find this approach best when it comes to solving most REST API design doubts.